# excel VBA to sort a different sheet than the active one

Tags: vba, excel

I was wondering if there is a way to have my macro do the below:

I want it to run this code on sheet2:

```
Dim arrColOrder As Variant, ndx As Integer
Dim Found As Range, counter As Integer

'Place the column headers in the end result order you want.
arrColOrder = Array("*Item1*", "*Item2*", "*Item3*", "*Item4*")

counter = 1

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

For ndx = LBound(arrColOrder) To UBound(arrColOrder)

    Set Found = Rows("1:1").Find(arrColOrder(ndx), LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, _
                      SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False)

    If Not Found Is Nothing Then
        If Found.Column <> counter Then
            Found.EntireColumn.Cut
            Columns(counter).Insert Shift:=xlToRight
            Application.CutCopyMode = False
        End If
        counter = counter + 1
    End If
Next ndx

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Then run this code on sheet1:

'This will add three columns for the Item2, Item3, and the Item4 datapoints based on Item1 in column A.

```
    Columns("P:P").Select
    Selection.Insert Shift:=xlToRight, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
    Range("P1").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Item4"
    Columns("P:P").Select
    Selection.Insert Shift:=xlToRight, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
    Range("P1").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Item3"
    Columns("P:P").Select
    Selection.Insert Shift:=xlToRight, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
    Range("P1").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Item2"
    Range("P1:R1").Select
    Range("R1").Activate
    With Selection.Interior
        .Pattern = xlSolid
        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .Color = 15773696
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .PatternTintAndShade = 0
    End With
    Range("P2").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=VLOOKUP(RC[10],Sheet1!C[-15]:C[-14],2,FALSE)"
    Range("P2").Select
Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("P2:P" & Cells(Rows.Count, "Z").End(xlUp).Row)
    Range("Q2").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=VLOOKUP(RC[9],Sheet1!C[-16]:C[-14],3,FALSE)"
    Range("Q2").Select
Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("Q2:Q" & Cells(Rows.Count, "Z").End(xlUp).Row)
    Range("R2").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=VLOOKUP(RC[8],Sheet1!C[-17]:C[-14],4,FALSE)"
    Range("R2").Select
Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("R2:R" & Cells(Rows.Count, "Z").End(xlUp).Row)

End Sub
```

Is there a way? So far all it does it run both on the active sheet and that makes everything mess up.

All I want is to re-order the things on sheet 2 so when I do the V lookup on sheet 1 they are in the right order!

Please help, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So far all it does it run both on the active sheet and that makes everything mess up.

Aha, you've found one of the pitfalls in using `.Activate` and `.Select`.  [Here's a good](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba-macros) SO thread that outlines how to avoid using `.Select`.

Further to your question, how do you run two codes on two different sheets?  It's not too hard - just create two `Worksheet` variables, and use `With` statements.

For example, here's a code that places "A" in Sheet1, cell A1, and "A" in Sheet2, cell A2:

```
Sub test()
Dim ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet

'Let's define our variables.  For worksheets, like Ranges, you need to use 'Set'
Set ws1 = Sheets("Sheet1")
Set ws2 = Sheets("Sheet2")

 'Now, we want to work with each specific worksheet. Let's choose one at a time.
With ws1
    .Cells(1, 1).Value = "A"
    ' Do other code here, to happen on ws1.  Note the use of the '.' before '.Cells', this tells excel to use
    ' ws1.cells(1,1) ...
End With

With ws2
    .Cells(2, 1).Value = "A"
    'Do other stuff here for worksheet2
End With

End Sub
```

A 'quick and dirty' fix for your code is, right before the line that you want to use on Sheet2, enter the line `Sheets("Sheet2").Activate`.

Edit: Just more notes on using the `ws1` and `ws2`:

```
With ws1
 .cells(1,1).Value = "A"
End with
```

is the *same thing* as `ws1.cells(1,1).Value = "A"`.  You use `With` because you can put all your code in there, that is to be run with Worksheet1.  In your code, if you create a `ws1` and `ws2` variable, and set these to the right sheets, you can just put `ws1.` before all the ranges you want to select in that worksheet, and `ws2.` for the second worksheet.  Does that make sense?

If you want to select range "A1:B10" in worksheet 1, then delete the range, you could do

```
With ws1
 .Range("A1:B10").Delete
End with
' is same as ws1.range("A1:B10").Delete
```

or

```
With ws1
 .Range(.Cells(1,1),.Cells(10,2)).Delete
End with
' is same as ws1.Range(ws1.Cells(1,1),ws1.CElls(10,2)).Delete
```

Note the `.` before `Cells`.  This is due to the fact that you want this range to refer to sheet1's range, not any other sheet.  Leaving out the `.` could potentially cause issues if another sheet becomes active during the macro.

edit2:

After all the above, I've edited your OP code to avoid using `.Select`.  You should be able to study this and think, and see what I did:

```
Sub test()
Dim ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet
Set ws1 = Sheets("Sheet1")
Set ws2 = Sheets("Sheet2")

''' RUN THE BELOW ON SHEET 2
Dim arrColOrder As Variant, ndx As Integer
Dim Found As Range, counter As Integer

'Place the column headers in the end result order you want.
arrColOrder = Array("*Item1*", "*Item2*", "*Item3*", "*Item4*")

counter = 1

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

For ndx = LBound(arrColOrder) To UBound(arrColOrder)

    Set Found = ws2.Rows("1:1").Find(arrColOrder(ndx), LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, _
                      SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False)

    If Not Found Is Nothing Then
        If Found.Column <> counter Then
            Found.EntireColumn.Cut
            ws2.Columns(counter).Insert Shift:=xlToRight
            Application.CutCopyMode = False
        End If
        counter = counter + 1
    End If
Next ndx

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

''' RUN THE BELOW ON SHEET1
With ws1
    .Columns("P:P").Insert Shift:=xlToRight, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
    .Range("P1").FormulaR1C1 = "Item4"
    .Columns("P:P").Insert Shift:=xlToRight, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
    .Range("P1").FormulaR1C1 = "Item3"
    .Columns("P:P").Insert Shift:=xlToRight, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
    .Range("P1").FormulaR1C1 = "Item2"
   ' .Range("P1:R1").Select 'Don't need this, since you don't do anything with it.
    With .Range("R1").Interior
        .Pattern = xlSolid
        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .Color = 15773696
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .PatternTintAndShade = 0
    End With
    .Range("P2").FormulaR1C1 = "=VLOOKUP(RC[10],Sheet1!C[-15]:C[-14],2,FALSE)"
    .Range("P2").AutoFill Destination:=Range("P2:P" & Cells(Rows.Count, "Z").End(xlUp).Row)
    .Range("Q2").FormulaR1C1 = "=VLOOKUP(RC[9],Sheet1!C[-16]:C[-14],3,FALSE)"
    .Range("Q2").AutoFill Destination:=Range("Q2:Q" & Cells(Rows.Count, "Z").End(xlUp).Row)
    .Range("R2").FormulaR1C1 = "=VLOOKUP(RC[8],Sheet1!C[-17]:C[-14],4,FALSE)"
    .Range("R2").AutoFill Destination:=Range("R2:R" & Cells(Rows.Count, "Z").End(xlUp).Row)
End Sub
```

Comment: I just tried to impliment the fix above with ws1 and ws2 and it still sorted the data on the active sheet only..

Comment: I also tried the "dirty fix" however after making sheet 2 the active sheet how do i switch back to sheet 1? Thanks

Comment: OH! sorry again, on the "quick fix" changing the active sheet, that works, but I cant get it to use the wild card EX: Sheets("name*").Activate -- cause sometimes it will be name_1 name_2 ect.  Thoughts?

Comment: I've updated my post - check it out and hopefully it works! Let me know if not, and I'll look into your question.  Edit: Can you clarify? Your sheets won't always be "Sheet1", "Sheet2"? If no, what's the naming convention for them?

Comment: well it pulls based on how many times you have exported something so if only once it is numbers_all  then the 2nd time you export its numbers_all-1 and the third time is numbers_all-2 ect. so i wanted to use the wild card * behind the numbers_all* to catch any variable

Comment: And that's to get the Sheet names?  How do you know, if there are up to ten sheets ( `numbers_all-10`), which one is going to be your "worksheet 1" and "2" for the macro?

Comment: I will always run this macro on numbers_all but if i have exported the list 10 times then the name would be numbers_all-10. It will be the same data, and sheet 2 will always be named the same, just the first worksheet will change names

Comment: Do you know enough VB to be able to change/edit the worksheet names in that macro, or would you like me to help guide?

Comment: no I can write that, I just didnt know if i could use a wildcard to prevent more code. Thanks for everything! the code above works great! thank you very much for taking the time to help!!

Comment: Glad to have helped! (If you don't mind, marking as answer?)  And I think you're okay in using the wildcard, just make sure it's a good use of one, and not like `"she*"` which would get `Sheet1`, `Sheet2`, etc. etc. (I guess for this example use `"sheet1-*"` or something.

Answer (score 0):

Create an excel worksheet object. You can sort that.

```
Dim ws As Excel.Worksheet
Set ws = Worksheets("Sheet2")

'Then you do a sort on ws.Range("A:A").Sort
```